# Wrong dominance frontier

Tags: compiler-construction, graph-theory, ssa

My problem is probably misunderstanding of dominance frontier algorithm.

I am implementing SSA form according to this paper: https://c9x.me/compile/bib/ssa.pdf

It seems my algorithm for computing dominance frontier is correct and matches with pseudo-code in paper (Figure 2. Calculation of DF), however, it gives weird results.

Paper says:

> The dominator tree of CFG has exactly the same set of nodes as CFG but has a very different set of edges.
> The words predecessor, successor, path always refer to CFG here. The words parent, child, ancestor, descendant always refer to the dominator tree.

So I hope I applied control flow successors and dominator tree children in proper places. Below is my logic, where I cannot see any troubles. **df** is dominance frontier, **idom** is immediate dominator.

```c
/* Bottom-up tree traversal. */
static void traverse_cfg_post_order(ir_vector_t *out, struct ir_node *ir)
{
    vector_foreach(ir->idom_back, i) {
        struct ir_node *x = vector_at(ir->idom_back, i);
        if (x)
            traverse_cfg_post_order(out, x);
    }
    vector_push_back(*out, ir);
}

static void dominance_frontier(struct ir_node *ir)
{
    ir_vector_t post_order = {0};
    traverse_cfg_post_order(&post_order, ir);

    vector_foreach(post_order, i) {
        struct ir_node *x = vector_at(post_order, i);
        vector_free(x->df);

        struct ir_node *succs[2] = {0};
        control_flow_successors(x, &succs[0], &succs[1]);

        for (uint64_t j = 0; j < 2; ++j) {
            struct ir_node *y = succs[j];
            if (y && y->idom != x)
                vector_push_back(x->df, y);
        }

        vector_foreach(x->idom_back, j) {
            struct ir_node *z = vector_at(x->idom_back, j);
            vector_foreach(z->df, k) {
                struct ir_node *y = vector_at(z->df, k);
                if (y && y->idom != x)
                    vector_push_back(x->df, y);
            }
        }
    }

    vector_free(post_order);
}
```

My assumptions:

- Dominator tree algorithm is correct
- Function taking control flow successors is correct

Below is dominator tree with calculated dominance frontier (DF). For some reason it always takes one conditional branch and evidently dominance frontier is incorrect.

[Dominator tree image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tr9O6.png)

Comment: Sorry. Algorithm is correct and my assumption about dominator tree was wrong.  The problem was in wrong dominator tree.